# Delete row in listview and database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, delete-row

I design a custom listview with image, text and an Image button delete. When i press imagebutton, i want to app delete this row on listview also on table database and refresh listview. Problem is app not delete correctly id. Example: id on table database is 1 2 3 4 position on list view is 0 1 2 3. After delete a row: id is 1 2 4 and position is 0 1 2. anyone help me delete correctly row on listview and database then refresh listview, please. here is code:

```
  listViewMon.setAdapter(new CartArrayAdapter(ctx, R.layout.single_list_cart, listtao));
    listViewMon.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public String variable;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
            CartGetSetListView o = (CartGetSetListView) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            variable = o.getTenmon().toString();

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    CartActivity.this);
            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("XÓA MÓN");
            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Bạn có muốn xóa " + "[" + variable + "]" + String.valueOf(position) + " khỏi giỏ hàng?");
            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.warning);
            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            db.delete_order("tbl_order", String.valueOf(position + 1));
                            Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Đã xóa: " + variable + String.valueOf(position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            load_cart();

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Delete row :

```
    public void delete_order(String table_name, String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from " + table_name + " where ID_book ='" + id + "'");
}
```

add data from table to array list

```
 public void load_cart() {

    ctx = this;
    db.querydata("Create table if not exists tbl_order (ID_book integer primary key, IDCH_book integer not null, ID_table integer not null, IDmon_book integer not null, TT_tt text not null, Datetime_book tex not null)");
    Cursor curs = db.getdata("select * from tbl_order, tbl_mon_app where tbl_order.IDmon_book = tbl_mon_app.IDMon");
    int cc = curs.getCount();
    if (curs.moveToFirst()) {

        while (!curs.isAfterLast()) {
            ArrImgUrl.add(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("ImgUrl")));
            curs.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    if (curs.moveToFirst()) {

        while (!curs.isAfterLast()) {
            ArrTenmon.add(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("TenMon")));
            curs.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    if (curs.moveToFirst()) {

        while (!curs.isAfterLast()) {         
            ArrGia.add(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("Gia")));
            curs.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {

        listtao.add(new CartGetSetListView(ArrImgUrl.get(i), ArrTenmon.get(i), ArrGia.get(i), "delete1"));

    }
    curs.close();
    db.close();
}
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CartArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CartGetSetListView> {
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
URL url;
Bitmap bmp = null;

public CartArrayAdapter(Context ctx, int resourceId, List<CartGetSetListView> objects) {
    super(ctx, resourceId, objects);
    resource = resourceId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    CartGetSetListView cart = getItem(position);

    ImageView imgMon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgMon);
    TextView tenMon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tenMon);
    tenMon.setText(cart.getTenmon());

    ImageButton imgDel = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Del);
    TextView gia = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.giaMon);
    gia.setText("Giá: " + cart.getGia() + " vnđ");

    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(cart.getImgurlmon()).fit().into(imgMon);

    String uri1 = "drawable/" + cart.getImgdel();
    int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getPackageName());
    Drawable image1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource1);
    imgDel.setImageDrawable(image1);

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

cartgetsetListview

```
public class CartGetSetListView {
public CartGetSetListView(String imgurlMon, String tenmon, String gia, String imgDel) {
    super();
    this.imgurlmon = imgurlMon;
    this.tenmon = tenmon;
    this.gia = gia;
    this.imgdel = imgDel;
}

private String imgurlmon;
private String tenmon;
private String gia;
private String imgdel;

public String getImgurlmon() {
    return imgurlmon;
}
public void setImgurlmon(String imgurlmon) {
    this.imgurlmon = imgurlmon;
}

public String getTenmon() {
    return tenmon;
}

public void setTenmon(String tenmon) {
    this.tenmon = tenmon;
}

public String getGia() {
    return gia;
}

public void setGia(String gia) {
    this.gia = gia;
}

public String getImgdel() {
    return imgdel;
}

public void setImgdel(String imgdel) {
    this.imgdel = imgdel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question and also post the `CartGetSetListView` class?

Comment: @pleft  i was updated file CartGetSetListView.java

Comment: delete a record by id or row field, not by index in listview.

Comment: using position + 1 will not reflect id, it may at first As soon as you delete anything but the last row then there will be mismatches e.g with 3 rows id's 1,2 and 3 at first position + 1 will match the respective id's. delete 2nd row (pos 1, therefore id 2) and you have id's 1 and 3 left. You need to get the id elsewhere. Perhaps CursorAdapter, perhaps another complimentary array with id's.

Comment: listview start with 0 position and in your db position start with 1

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058405/unable-to-get-the-item-id-from-sqlite-database-to-delete-or-edit-the-list-item/47063048#47063048) of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add more a variable `bookid` to `CartGetSetListView`
2. Edit:

   listViewMon.setAdapter(new CartArrayAdapter(ctx, R.layout.single_list_cart, listtao));

   to

   CartArrayAdapter myadapter=  new CartArrayAdapter(ctx, R.layout.single_list_cart, listtao)
     listViewMon.setAdapter(myadapter);
3. Edit

   db.delete_order("tbl_order", String.valueOf(position + 1));

to

```
 String bookid=myadapter.getItem(position).bookid
 db.delete_order("tbl_order", bookid);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `adapter`, write a method 
`public int getID(int position)` 
to return the ID of the element in the `position`. Then when you get the `position` from the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. Get the ID by calling `adapter.getID(position)`. I would strongly advice against using `position+1` to obtain the ID for deleting the row from database. After successful deletion, you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter to update the listview. Also, you might wanna use `RecyclerView`. Its more efficient and powerful than `ListView`

Comment: see the last parameter of AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick

Comment: this method is called with four parameters, see the last one